# dereferencing an array in a struct (in C)

Tags: c, arrays, struct

Let's say I have a struct and the following functions:

struct in header file:

```
typedef struct {
uint8_t length;
uint8_t data[8];
} simple_vector;
```

function:

```
simple_vector* SD_cmd(uint8_t cmd, uint32_t arg, uint8_t crc, uint8_t read_cnt){

simple_vector vector;

//stuff happens and the simple_vector is manipulated

return &vector;
}
```

How do I go about accessing the non-zeroth element of an array using the -> operator?

Let's say a function returns a pointer to this struct:

```
simple_vector *response;
response = SD_cmd(8, 0x000001AA, 0x87, 5);
uint8_t value = response->data[3];
```

The last line in the above snippet does not return the correct value. I've debugged (on an mcu) and verified that the data[3] in the function is not the same as what I get when I dereference it outside of the function. Any thoughts?

Comment: The syntax is correct. What do you mean by "does not appear to work"?

Comment: It's the first line of that snippet that won't compile. The last line is fine. To get a definitive answer, you need to post a [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @user3386109: You should add the rest of the code. The first line is no valid syntax as-is. See [ask] and provide a [mcve]!

Comment: @RSahu `*structure struct1_ptr;` is a syntax error

Comment: `*structure struct1_ptr;` --> `structure *struct1_ptr;`

Comment: @M.M, yes. I was looking at just the line that tries to access the array of the `struct`.

Comment: I've updated the initial entry to include a trimmed version of my code. Apologies for the first line's syntax error, it was a mistake I made when I was just writing a generic version of the code.

Comment: @alk local variables stop existing when their function returns, so you access a dangling pointer

Comment: @alk If your function creates a `structure` using a `malloc`, you can safely return that pointer to the caller. Just keep in mind you have to `free` that memory when you no longer need it!

Comment: An array is not a pointer. You cannot "dereference an array".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're returning the address of a local variable. When control leaves the block containing the variable definition (in this case, your function), the variable gets destroyed, and you're left with an invalid pointer.

Your code has undefined behavior.

You should also check if your compiler has warning options for this case. E.g. gcc has `-Wreturn-local-addr` (which I believe is enabled by default), which warns you about this situation.

---

To solve this problem, you could have your function take a pointer to a struct to write the results into. This would make it the caller's responsibility to manage the memory associated with the struct.

You could also return a struct by value, which would copy it to the caller (behind the scenes this probably compiles to something like solution #1; functions returning structs are usually implemented by making them take a hidden pointer argument anyway).

Or you could `malloc` a struct dynamically. Then you have to check for errors (a `NULL` return from `malloc`) and it becomes the caller's responsibility to `free` the returned pointer.

Finally, you could make the function return nothing (`void`) and instead use a global variable to communicate values back to the caller. This is usually not recommended because global variables can lead to some hard to understand program logic (and hard to find bugs).

Comment: That's not necessarily the case: he could have called `malloc` inside his function which in turn returned the pointer to the newly allocated `structure`.

Comment: @mw215 He could, but he didn't. Look at the code in the question.

Comment: So essentially I'd have to use malloc and then free it after I'm done using. Am I correct in assuming it's better to return a pointer than just the simple_vector? I'm doing so because I don't want the program to have to copy an entirely new struct.

Comment: @alk I've added a couple of possible solutions (in order from most to least recommended).

Answer (score 0):

> How do I go about accessing the non-zeroth element of an array using the -> operator?

You can do it by making your variables accessible in the first place. Assuming the "non zeroth" and "tenth" elements in an array of 8 elements are typos, what you might easily do is correctly create and manage a pointer to valid memory which is also *accessible from your caller function*. One obvious possibility is doing it *dynamically*. Here is a quick demonstration fix, based on your code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    uint8_t length;
    uint8_t data[8];
} simple_vector;

simple_vector* SD_cmd(uint8_t cmd, uint32_t arg, uint8_t crc, uint8_t read_cnt)
{
    simple_vector *vector = malloc(sizeof(simple_vector)); // pointer to malloc'd memory
    //stuff happens and the simple_vector is manipulated
    vector->data[3] = 42;
    return vector; //return the pointer
}

int main()
{
    if((simple_vector *response = SD_cmd(8, 0x000001AA, 0x87, 5)) == NULL){
        printf("Memory allocation error\n");
        return(1);
    }
    uint8_t value = response->data[3]; //the "last" line in question
    printf("%hhu\n", value);
    free(response);       //free the memory once you don't need it !
    return 0;
}
```

> The last line in the above snippet does not return the correct value

```
> ./test
  42
```

Please note how elegant and idiomatic to C such procedures are.